# Using Javascript if statements with and operator and selectors to create navigation bar

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to create my own navigation bar using Javascript, this is what I have so far.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
<nav class="menuL">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#!/page_portfolio" id="portmenu"><span></span>portfolio</a></li>
            <ul id="submenu">
                <li id="first"><a href="#!/">Wine</a></li>
                <li id="second"><a href="#!/">Landscape</a></li>
                <li id="third"><a href="#!/">Divers</a></li>
            </ul>
<script>
    $('#submenu').hide();
</script>
<script>
        if ($('#portmenu').mouseover() || $('#first').mouseover() || $('#second').mouseover() || $('#third').mouseout()) {
            $('#submenu').show();
        } else {
            $('#submenu').hide();
}
});
</script>
```

The submenu is infact being hidden but when I hover over portmenu, the submenu does not appear.. any ideas on what is wrong? I'm new to javascript so I have no idea if im using the selectors, OR operators and the if statements correctly.

Basically what I'm trying to do is, if the main portmenu is hovered over or if first, second and third are being hovered over, then show the sub menu. Otherwise, hide it. I'm trying to do this because if I just create a function which shows the submenu if portmenu is being hovered over, then the moment I hover of the text 'portfolio' the submenu goes away.

Comment: This kind of thing can optionally be done with CSS and CSS pseduo-classes without javascript

Comment: You're not using `.mouseover()` correctly. What you're looking for is `.hover()`

Comment: Nothing you've shown is correct. It's a strange mixture of HTML with invalid JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/pcW6d/)***

You should probably do something more along these lines by taking advantage of [jQuery's hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/):

```
$('#submenu').hide();
$('#portmenu, #first, #second, #third').hover(function(){
 //in
  $('#submenu').show();
},function(){
 //out
  $('#submenu').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it CSS only:

```
#menu > #submenu{
    display: none;
}
#menu:hover > #submenu{
    display: block;
}
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/Wp5sF/

Comment: Okay thanks, btw, how come it is not
#menu > #portmenu > #submenu{
    display: none;
}
#menu > #portmenu:hover > #submenu{
    display: block;
}

Comment: @user216485 You can't do that because `#submenu` isn't a child/descendant of `#portmenu`. Do you mind IE6? On IE6 `:hover` only works on anchors, but on modern browsers you can do it with every element.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion to fix your code.
([**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/jwu2B/))

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#submenu').hide();
  $('#menu').on('mouseover', function (){$('#submenu').show()});
  $('#menu').on('mouseout', function (){$('#submenu').hide()});
});
```

Comment: @user216485, I just noticed that you have not accepted answers on your questions. By accepting one answer you give the ones that helped you points/reputation. So please check your many questions you have made and accept the best answers. 1 answer per question. You get 2 points we get 15. This is why people answer, to get reputation. Cheers